# Interface 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface' not found in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I upload laravel project in server,

After upload show `HTTP ERROR 500` in http://myWebsite.com.

I run this code:

```
sudo chmod 755 -R laravel
chmod -R o+w laravel/storage
```

And add `.htaccess` in root project:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I run this code:

```
php artisan cache:clear,
php artisan composer dump-autoload
```

Show this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php on line 25
```

How to issue this problem?

Comment: try 'composer dump-autoload -o' without the artisan framework. If that doesn't work, try composer update --no-scripts' that will also bypass the laravel commands in the composer.json file.

Comment: Have the same issue! `update --no-scripts` and `composer update --no-scripts` didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried updating composer and re-initializing your terminal? `php composer.phar self-update`

Answer (score 0):

In your bootstrap.php file, check if you require `__DIR__.'/../autoload.php'`